# F7, F8, F9 media keys no longer works in High Sierra 10.13.1

Tags: itunes, safari

Buttons other than F7, F8 and F9 are working perfectly fine. I use Safari, and I haven't downloaded Google Play Music in Chrome extensions either. The buttons don't work on iTunes but anything else.

Answer (score 1):

First I would prefer to **restart** Mac system.
you can change your function shortcut keys.

**Change the behavior of function keys on your Mac**

You can use the top row of keys on your Apple keyboard as standard function keys or to control built-in Mac features.

**If your Apple keyboard has icons printed on some of the keys on its top row,**

these keys can be used to perform the special features shown in each icon. They can also be used as standard function keys (F1–F12). 
The action performed by standard function keys varies depending on the app you're using, or depending on the keyboard shortcuts listed in the Keyboard & Mouse pane of System Preferences:
By default, pressing one of these keys performs the special feature indicated by the icon printed on the key. For example, pressing the keys with speaker icons adjusts the volume.

**If you prefer the top row of keys to always behave as standard function keys without holding the Fn key:**

1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu.
2. Click Keyboard.
3. Click the Keyboard tab if it's not already highlighted.
4. Select "Use all
   F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"

With this option enabled, the keys on the top row act as standard function keys (F1–F12). To use a feature indicated by the icon printed on a key, hold Fn while pressing the key.

Answer (score 0):

The media keys (F7...F9) changed behavior in macOS 10.13.

> Apple just released High Sierra and it brought good things and annoying things : they changed the behaviour of the media controller keys, they no longer control itunes, they control the video playback in safari. This pissed off a lot of people including me, so I just created a menu bar app to proxy media key events to iTunes/Spotify while Apple fixes this. It doesn't support touchbar yet, only physical buttons.

See [HIGH SIERRA MEDIA KEY ENABLER](http://milgra.com/high-sierra-media-key-enabler.html) for a solution.